# Dijit buttons don't work when I move to a different page

Tags: javascript, dojo, mendix

[UPDATE]

Improved code according to advice here.

--

I have build a grid using dijit and dgrid:

```
define([
...
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, ...) {

    return declare("MyGrid.widget.MyGrid", [ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin ], {

        deleteButton: new MendixButton({
            className: "btn mx-button claro haasgridbutton",
            iconClass: "dijitIconDelete"
        }),

        ...

        postCreate: function () {
        ...
            addButtons();
        },
        ...
        addButtons: function () {
            ...
            dojoConstruct.place(this.deleteButton.domNode, this.objectButtonsNode);
            this.deleteButton.on("Click", dojo.hitch(this, function () {
                this._deleteObjectDialog();
            }));
        },
    });
});

require(["MyGrid/widget/MyGrid"]);
```

For whatever reason the delete button (or any other) does not work if I move away from the page and come back. the function `deleteObjectDialog();` is simply not called and I don't know why, neither do I know how to debug this.
The Debugger starts at the function and I can't find the 'onClick' part using the Inspector.

Comment: If you would make that function a seperate function in your file and reference to it, you can actually set a breakpoint there instead. What I'm expecting is that your `this` reference might be wrong at the point where it is no longer working. Is there any chance you can make a working example?

Comment: It is working. It's just not working when I switch pages.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using here is wrong. The events are not attached using `set`. They are attached using `on`. And your reference of `this` is also not correct. Inside the `onClick` call, `this` would refer to the `deleteButton` and not the grid widget. Instead of:

```
this.deleteButton.set("onClick", function () {
                l_this._deleteObjectDialog();
            });
```

It should be:

```
this.deleteButton.on("Click", dojo.hitch(this, function () {
                this._deleteObjectDialog();
            }));
```

Comment: The function is not called? Have you tried using `dojo/on` ?